# Is it possible to install only MongoDB command line tools on MacOS?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I'm working with docker and containers and I'd like to install and use only mongodb command line tools (mongodump, mongorestore etc ...)

I unsuccessfully checked the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/).

Is it possible to install the command line tools only?

Comment: Also see: [DBA StackExchange: Is it possible to install just the mongo Shell?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/196455/9345) which provides links to download just the `mongo` shell. There currently isn't a separate download for just the command-line tools on macOS, but you won't be saving many bytes if you need all but `mongod` and `mongos`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was totally easy in May 2018 - everything was at the top level of https://brew.sh and self-proclaimed "The Missing Package Manager for macOS (or Linux)"

Install https://brew.sh to get homebrew system running and then

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community
brew install mongodb-database-tools
```

Now in late 2020, the tool no longer meets the criteria to be listed as a top-level installation, so you have to first tap a cask for installation.

Also, the tools are now available separate from the database engine separate from compass (which embeds the former). These links work if you don’t want to `brew` the tools.

- https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/tools
- https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community

Comment: The whole database and tools is so small and easy to update, just install mongodb and you’ll have all the tools native.

Comment: Hi and thanks bmike, do you know if there's an installable brew package like mongodb-org-tools on ubuntu?

Comment: No - I’m not familiar with mongodb-org-tools @LucaAnceschi

Answer (score 16):

I tried all the proposed solutions but they did not work with me, I downloaded these tools by:

```
brew install mongodb/brew/mongodb-database-tools
```

Comment: @Goldy Thanks for bumping this - I’ve updated my post with the official links.

Comment: You might also want to run `brew link mongodb-database-tools` to set up all the symlinkes in your bin folder. The install command did not do that automatically for me as I already had an old installation of mongo.

Answer (score 12):

As for today, the correct answer is this:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible now.

```sh
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community-shell
```

Link: https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew

Comment: incorrect, `mongodb-community-shell` comes without the tools he needs

Comment: This does not install mongorestore, mongodump, etc.